# Why does updating state from fetch result updates the whole array of objects while rendering?

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, fetch, use-state, reverse-geocoding

I am having problem i want to get the city name based on the coordinates included in the workouts array of objects. This is the link to the [Files](https://github.com/kashcodernyc/react-mapty/tree/master/src) and [project](https://react-mapty.netlify.app/) and [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-hill-ykffj?file=/src/App.js)

```
    export const WorkoutsData = [
  {
  id: 1,
  coords: {latitude: 56.27360151291927, 
  longitude:-82.84886256490017},
  },
  
  {
  id: 2,
  coords: {latitude: 49.27360151291927, 
  longitude: -75.84886256490017},
  },

  {
  id: 3,
  coords: {latitude: 39.27360151291927, 
  longitude: -79.84886256490017},
  }
];



import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { WorkoutsData } from "./WorkoutLocation";

const App = () => {
  const [workouts, setWorkouts] = useState(WorkoutsData);
  const [cityName, setCityName] = useState([]);

  const id = (Date.now() + "").slice(-10);

  useEffect(() => {
    workouts.map((workout) => {
      fetch(
        `https://geocode.xyz/${workout.coords.latitude},${workout.coords.longitude}?geoit=json`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          setCityName([`${result.staddress}, ${result.city}`]);
        });
    });
  }, [workouts]);

  return (
    <>
      <div key={id}>
        {workouts.map((workout) => {
          return <h2 key={workout.id}>{`${cityName}`}</h2>;
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I did some edits on the code and managed to get unique location name, but this time i wouldn't get the location name  for the first workout object. Then the location name would be passed on to the second object.

[image: rendering location]

Comment: You keep overwriting cityName as you fetch location of each workout. Maybe you could build an array of cityNames and then store and read from that in state.

Comment: i updated  setCityName(`${result.staddress}, ${result.city}`)  to
setCityName(res => [...res, `${result.staddress}, ${result.city}`]) and my usestate to  const [cityname, setCityName] = useState([]);

how do i map through the cityname array and diplay cityname for each object?

Comment: when i console .log(cityName) i get the same cityName twice

Comment: Your `cityName` variable only holds one string. You are overwriting the same string every time. If you want to save a list of strings, use a list.

Comment: i updated setCityName(${result.staddress}, ${result.city}) to setCityName(res => [...res, [${result.staddress}, ${result.city]}]) 

when i render i get all the location name in one workout-container

Answer (score 0):

You should be more clear with the code you provide. You are omitting parts of your code which would make more clear how your components are structured.

You seem to be approaching the problem the wrong way.

- First of all, your state should hold a list instead of a single string if you want to render a list of workout locations.

```
    const [cityName, setCityName] = useState(null)

    workouts.map((exercise) => {
        ...
        setCityName(`${result.staddress}, ${result.city}`)
        ...
    }
```

The above just sets "cityName" to a single string every time you look up another location. It should contain a list of strings.

- Next, your workouts should probably be passed as props to the component (not sure from the few code snippets you provided).
- And then in the end - when you render the result - you go through all the workouts from the "workouts" state, and render something that is not even in the "workouts" state: you render the "cityName" state instead, which now holds the location of the last workout you looked up:

```
return (
        <>
            workouts.map((workout) => {
                <h2 className = "workout-title">{cityName}</h2>
            }
        </>
    )
```

The following might be a better way to solve your issue (not sure since I can't be sure from the limited code you showed if that is exactly you want to do):

**WorkoutLocations.js:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export const WorkoutLocations = ({ workoutsList }) => {
    const [cities, setCities] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getLocation = async (workout) =>
                fetch(`https://geocode.xyz/${workout.coords.latitude},${workout.coords.longitude}?geoit=json`)
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((res) => `${res.staddress}, ${res.city}`);                    
        const getLocations = async () =>
            Promise.all(workoutsList.map((workout) => getLocation(workout)));        
        getLocations().then((res) => setCities(res));
    }, [workoutsList]);

    return (
        <>
            {cities &&
                cities.map((city, id) => (
                    <h2 key={id} className="workout-title">
                        {city}
                    </h2>
                ))}
        </>
    );
};
```

**(inside your app):**

```
import { WorkoutLocations } from "./WorkoutLocations"

...

const workouts = [
    {
        coords: {
            latitude: 41.27360151291927,
            longitude: -72.84886256490017
        }
    },
    {
        coords: {
            latitude: 40.7128,
            longitude: -74.006
        }
    }
];

...

return (
    <WorkoutLocations
        workoutsList={workouts}
    />
)
```

You can see the working code in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-rumple-chmmh).

Comment: Thanks Ruben!
I tried your code, but it would return undefined. I made some edits to the code. can you look at it and give me any suggestion.

Comment: Did you try the CodeSandbox link? The code works there.

Comment: If you don't include the whole code, it is very hard for me to  give any more suggestions. I cannot see the whole component structure. You are calling the useState hook, but not from within a function. When you don't show the full code, I cannot see what is going wrong.

Comment: Also, when you edit your code, you should add the new code under the initial question you posted, not just change the whole question. Otherwise my answer becomes completely irrelevant from the perspective of new visitors who didn't see your initial question.

Comment: this is my first time posting a question, so i'm not aware of the rules and procedures. Also here are all my codes https://github.com/kashcodernyc/react-mapty/tree/master/src

Comment: What I meant was not to give me a link to your whole codebase, but to create a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and clearly state the problem/ask a question. Only then can somebody (maybe) help you.

Comment: i added link to the project let me know if it gives any idea about the problem

Comment: i added sandbox link as well

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/github-geocoding-cities-list-b65cy

Comment: It's still the same issue, you are loading the data for all the locations just ONCE when your component is mounted, so you have to set ALL the cities in the state.